# I am working on linq to entity framework and i have issue in getting data in my service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
  public VirtualNumber getVirtualNumber(string address)
    {
        using (PushMessageDBContext dbcontext = new PushMessageDBContext())
        {
            var vNumber = from n in dbcontext.VirtualNumber
                          where n.Address == address
                          select new
                          {
                              VirtualNumber = n,
                              KeyWords = n.Keywords.OrderBy(k => k.KeywordName)
                          };
           // return vNumber;
        }
    }
```

and getting error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable< KeyWords>>' to 'SMPushMessage.Models.VirtualNumber'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) SMPushMessage   D:\ServerProjects\SMPushMessage\smpushmessage\SMPushMessage\SMPushMessage\Services\imp\VirtualNumberService.cs  22  Active

can any one ,tell me how to solve??

Comment: You are returning a single VirtualNumber but you select multiple.

Comment: What do you need? 1 or multiple? That's not clear from your question.

Comment: i need 1 virtual number whose keyword may be multiple

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting an anonymous type. If you want to return a `VirtualNumber` you should first select that.

```
(from n in dbcontext.VirtualNumber
 where n.Address == address
 select n).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you post your `VirtualNumber` class I could help you further.

Like grmbl pointed out, that will return you a list. If you want a single object, you'll need `.FirstOrDefault()`

**Edit:** assuming that `VirtualNumber` containts a list of `Keywords`

```
(from n in dbcontext.VirtualNumber
 where n.Address == address
 select new VirtualNumber
 {
     KeyWords = n.Keywords.OrderBy(k => k.KeywordName)
 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, your select is not ok, I think should be like bellow (I do not know the properties of VirtualNumber):

```
select new VirtualNumber 
                          {
                              KeyWords = n.Keywords.OrderBy(k => k.KeywordName)
                          }.FirstOrDefault();
```